# Angular 7 show button in the last position of the array

Tags: javascript, angular

quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme con esto.
tengo un Array donde necesito mostrar un botón (añadir elemento) y despues de pulsado solo se siga mostrando en la ultima posición

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray, FormBuilder} from "@angular/forms";
import {Evento, EventosService} from "@jdl-solutions/koguiapi";
import {EventoStoreService} from "../../../eventos/listas-eventos/evento-store.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-new-reserva-detail-form',
  templateUrl: './add-new-reserva-detail-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-new-reserva-detail-form.component.sass'],
  providers: [EventosService]
})
export class AddNewReservaDetailFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() modal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();  //Salida de evento para cerrar modal
  @Output() reservaNewRegistry: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); //Salida del formulario
  reservaNewRegistryForm: FormGroup; //Formulario
  reservaNewRegistryList: FormArray; //Datos Matriz

  imagenComprobante = null;
  fotoComprobante: File = null;
  debe: number = 0;
  monto: number = 0;
  eventosList;
  eventoSelected: Evento;
  public evento: Evento;
  status;


  get DatosUsuarioFormGroup() {
    return this.reservaNewRegistryForm.get('datosUsuario') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, public eventosService: EventosService, private eventoStoreService: EventoStoreService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //Fragmento de codigo para realizar la consulta al API o no en caso de estar en el modulo de eventos o reservas
    if (this.eventoStoreService.eventoSelected != undefined) {
      //Se carga variable propagada que contiene el objeto EVENTO
      this.evento = this.eventoStoreService.eventoSelected;
      this.status = 'EVENTOS';
    } else {
      //Se llama al API para cargar los eventos ACTIVOS para mostrar en el select de la vista
      this.eventosService.getEmpresasByIdEventos('antioquia',
        '', 0, 0, [], [], '', 'response', true)
        .subscribe(res => {
          //Hacer if con codicion de evento activo. no se ha hecho ya que todos se cargan en borrador por ahora
          this.eventosList = res.body;
        });
      this.status = 'RESERVAS';
    }

    //Se crea formulario
    this.reservaNewRegistryForm = this.fb.group({
      datosUsuario: this.fb.array([this.createDatosUsuario()])
    });

    //Se llena la lista con los datos de usuario
    this.reservaNewRegistryList = this.reservaNewRegistryForm.get('datosUsuario') as FormArray;
    console.log(this.reservaNewRegistryList.length);

  }

  //Grupo del formulario
  createDatosUsuario(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      nombre: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      apellido: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      correo: new FormControl('', [Validators.email, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)]),
      tipoDocumento: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      documentoID: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      telefono: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      genero: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      abono: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      debe: new FormControl(''),
    })
  }

  /**
   * @name addDatosUsuario
   * @desc Metodo para añadir una nueva tarjeta
   */
  addDatosUsuario() {
    this.reservaNewRegistryList.push(this.createDatosUsuario());
  }

  /**
   * @name removeDatosUsuario
   * @desc Metodo para eliminar una tarjeta
   * @param index
   */
  removeDatosUsuario(index) {
    this.reservaNewRegistryList.removeAt(index);
  }

  /**
   * @name onFileComprobante
   * @desc Metodo que captura el comprobante ingresado y la convierte a base64 para propagar si se necesita
   *      y la guarda en formato
   *      para enviar al API
   * @param files
   */
  onFileComprobante(files: FileList) {
    let foto = files.item(0);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imagenComprobante = event.target.result; //Base64 para propagar en otras vistas
    };
    this.fotoComprobante = foto; //File a enviar al API
    reader.readAsDataURL(foto);
    // if (this.foto.size > 3200000) {
    //   this.toastr.error('La imagen ingresada supera los 3MB, verifique la imagen y vuelva a cargarla.');
    //   this.deshabilitar = true;
    // } else {
    //   this.deshabilitar = false; //Se habilita boton
    // }
  }

  /**
   * @name calculoDebe
   * @desc Metodo que calcula el el valor que se debe en la tarjeta
   * @param abono
   */
  calculoDebe(abono) {
    let num = parseInt(abono);
    this.debe = this.evento.valor - num;
  }

  /**
   * @name closeModal
   * @desc Metodo que emite un evento al componente padre para cerrar la modal
   */
  closeModal() {
    this.modal.emit('close');
  }

  /**
   * @name onsubmit
   * @desc Metodo que valida el formulario, se construye el objeto y se envia
   */
  onSubmit() {
    //Falta añadir el array de personas al obj y desbloquear el boton
    console.log(this.reservaNewRegistryForm.value);

    //Obtener la fecha para enviar al api
    let fecha = new Date().getTime();

    //Se pasa a la variable form los datos del responsable
    let responsable = this.reservaNewRegistryForm.value.datosUsuario[0];
    if (this.status === 'EVENTOS') {
      let formulario = {
        id: 0,
        empresa: this.evento.empresa,
        tipo: 'EVENTO',
        redId: this.evento.id,
        ref: "none",
        programacion: null,
        movimientos: [
          {
            estado: "NUEVO",
            registerAt: 15201265478,
            montoAbonado: 200000,
            fecha: 15201265478,
            notas: "No hay notas"
          }
        ],
        montoTotal: 500000,
        montoAbonado: 200000,
        createdAt: 15201265478,
        updatedAt: 152324587965,
        canceledAt: 15236547898,
        expireAt: 12547896320,
        estado: "COMPLETADA",
        cupos: 5,
        comentario: "sin comentarios",
        addMovimientos: [
          {
            adjunto: this.fotoComprobante,
            monto: this.monto,
            fecha: fecha,
            notas: "no hay notas"
          }
        ],
        responsable:
          {
            usuarioKogui: "none",
            nombre: responsable.nombre,
            apellido: responsable.apellido,
            tipoDocumento: responsable.tipoDocumento,
            documentoID: responsable.documentoID,
            telefono: responsable.telefono,
            correo: responsable.correo,
            genero: responsable.genero,
            nacimiento: "none",
            abono: responsable.abono,
            debe: responsable.debe,
            nota: "no hay notas"
          },
        personas: ''

      };
      console.log(formulario);
    } else {
      let formulario = {
        id: 0,
        empresa: this.eventoSelected.empresa,
        tipo: 'EVENTO',
        redId: this.eventoSelected.id,
        ref: "none",
        programacion: null,
        movimientos: [
          {
            estado: "NUEVO",
            registerAt: 15201265478,
            montoAbonado: 200000,
            fecha: 15201265478,
            notas: "No hay notas"
          }
        ],
        montoTotal: 500000,
        montoAbonado: 200000,
        createdAt: 15201265478,
        updatedAt: 152324587965,
        canceledAt: 15236547898,
        expireAt: 12547896320,
        estado: "COMPLETADA",
        cupos: 5,
        comentario: "sin comentarios",
        addMovimientos: [
          {
            adjunto: this.fotoComprobante,
            monto: this.monto,
            fecha: fecha,
            notas: "no hay notas"
          }
        ],
        responsable:
          {
            usuarioKogui: "none",
            nombre: responsable.nombre,
            apellido: responsable.apellido,
            tipoDocumento: responsable.tipoDocumento,
            documentoID: responsable.documentoID,
            telefono: responsable.telefono,
            correo: responsable.correo,
            genero: responsable.genero,
            nacimiento: "none",
            abono: responsable.abono,
            debe: this.debe,
            nota: "no hay notas"
          },
        personas: ''

      };
      console.log(formulario);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <form [formGroup]="reservaNewRegistryForm" (validSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let usuario of DatosUsuarioFormGroup.controls; let i = index;"
       formArrayName="datosUsuario">
    <!--Tarjeta-->
    <div class="main-card mb-3 card-reserva" [formGroupName]="i">
      <ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="tarjetaUsuario1">
        <ngb-panel id="tarjetaUsuario1">
          <ng-template ngbPanelHeader>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between" style="flex: auto">
              <button ngbPanelToggle class="btn m-0" style="font-size: 20px">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 3px"></i>
                Datos del Usuario
              </button>
              <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-shadow d-inline-flex align-items-center btn btn-primary mr-2"
                        (click)="addDatosUsuario()">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Añadir Reserva
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-shadow d-inline-flex align-items-center btn btn-primary mr-2"
                        (click)="removeDatosUsuario()" *ngIf="reservaNewRegistryForm.value.datosUsuario.length > 1">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Quitar Usuario
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                    <input name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" type="text"
                           class="form-control" formControlName="nombre" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                    <input name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" type="text"
                           class="form-control" formControlName="apellido" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="correo">Email</label>
                    <input name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Email" type="email"
                           class="form-control" formControlName="correo">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="tipoDocumento">Tipo Documento</label>
                    <select class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="tipoDocumento" id="tipoDocumento"
                            placeholder="Seleccionar Documento" required>
                      <option disabled selected>*Elija un tipo de documento</option>
                      <option value="CEDULA_CIUDADANIA">Cedula Ciudadanía</option>
                      <option value="PASAPORTE">Pasaporte</option>
                      <option value="CEDULA_EXTRANJERIA">Cedula Extrajería</option>
                      <option value="OTRO">Otro</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="documentoID">Documento</label>
                    <input name="documentoID" id="documentoID" placeholder="Documento" type="text"
                           class="form-control" formControlName="documentoID" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                    <input name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" type="number"
                           class="form-control" formControlName="telefono" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="position-relative form-group">
                <label>Genero</label>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <input formControlName="genero" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="M"
                         id="masculino" required>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="masculino">Masculino</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-3">
                  <input formControlName="genero" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="F"
                         id="femenino" required>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="femenino">Femenino</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="abono">Total del Abono</label>
                    <input name="abono" id="abono" placeholder="Total Abonado" type="text"
                           class="form-control" formControlName="abono" required (ngModelChange)="calculoDebe($event)">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="position-relative form-group">
                    <label for="debe">Debe</label>
                    <input name="debe" id="debe" type="text"
                           class="form-control" disabled [(ngModel)]="debe" formControlName="debe">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
      </ngb-accordion>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Cuando se de click en el botón añadir reserva debe ocultarse en la posición anterior y mostrarse en la posición siguiente

Comment: Hola, por favor edita tu pregunta y formularla en ingles, para preguntas en español usa https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Hi, please edit your question and do it in english, for spanish questions refer to https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Andrés, in a ngb-accordion, you must repeat the ngb-panel, not the ngb-accordion. So you must use some like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ngb-accordion #accordion formArrayName="datosUsuario" 
     [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="pannel0">
        <ngb-panel *ngFor="let group of form.get('datosUsuario').controls;let i=index" 
       [formGroupName]="i" 
       [id]="'pannel'+i">
               <ng-template ngbPanelHeader let-opened="opened">
                   <button ngbPanelToggle class="btn btn-link p-0">Datos del Usuario</button>
         </ng-template>
         <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
               Name: <input name="name" formControlName="name">
               <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
         </ng-template>
     </ngb-panel>
  </ngb-accordion>
</form>
```

Take account I nammed the "id" as pannel0,pannel1,pannel2... using `[id]="'pannel'+i"` and use the own tag ngbpanel to indicate the formGroupName.

Then you need use ViewChild to get the "accordion", see that I write as reference variable `#accordion`

```
  @ViewChild('accordion',{static:false}) accordion:NgbAccordion
```

I used a function that return a formGroup

```
  createFormGroup()
  {
    return new FormGroup({
        name:new FormControl()
      })
  }
```

So, our function "add()" is simple

```
  add()
  {
    const array=this.form.get('datosUsuario') as FormArray
    array.push(this.createFormGroup())
    setTimeout(()=>{
       this.accordion.expand("pannel"+(array.controls.length-1))
    })
  }
```

We need use a "setTimeout" to give time to Angular to create the "pannel"

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2o3kt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)